# Is relative entropy with respect to a pmf a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, information-theory

Is the relative entropy $D(p || q)$ with a fixed pmf $q$, continuous over $p$, where $p \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 , x_i \geq 0 \}$?

Comment: You don't want $p$ to be non-negative? That can get ugly, can't it?

Comment: Sorry, p should be non negative

Comment: Also, probably worth putting the definition of the relative entropy/KL divergence, if you assume the reader needs to be reminded what a probability distribution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $q_i > 0$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$. Then, assuming (as usual) that $0\log 0=0$ for the definition, we have 
$$\begin{align}
D(p\mid\mid q) &= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log_2 \frac{p_i}{q_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n  p_i \log_2 \frac{p_i}{q_i}
= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log_2 \frac{p_i}{q_i}  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n  p_i \log_2 p_i - \sum_{i=1}^n  p_i \log_2 q_i
\end{align}$$
Both terms are continuous with regard to $p$:

- the second is obvious: it is of the form $\langle p, y\rangle$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $y_i = \log_2 q_i$
- the first one because the function $\colon x\in[0,1]\mapsto (x\log_2 x)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x)$ is continuous.

If there exists $i\in \{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $q_i=0$, it is no longer true. Indeed, then you can have, for any $\varepsilon > 0$,  $D(p\mid\mid q) = \infty$ and $D(p^\prime \mid\mid q) < \infty$ while $\lVert p - p^\prime\rVert_1 \leq \varepsilon$.